# Android openGL black square bug

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-softkeyboard

I'm currently stuck in front of a problem.
I work on Android with API 19 with Eclipse IDE using Java.
I've done an Activity which contains some Layouts. And i've put in one of these layout a custom class which inherits from `GLSurfaceView` in order to provide a 3D rendering for the user.
But actually i have a problem on a specific device, the "Epson moverio" glasses which works with Android 4.04.
When the softkeyboard pops out, it shows me the `GLSurfaceView` and also a black square which have the same dimensions as `GLSurfaceView` and this black square is contiguous with the `GLSurfaceView`. I don't understand why i have this bug, because it works well on classic devices like samsung tablets and i have another version of the view on which i draw 2D shapes using canvas, and i don't get the black square problem, it seems that kind of problem happens only with openGL rendering context (i'm using openGL 2.0 ES).

- it seems that this bug occurs only when the softkeyboard pops on the screen.
- I tried to put an `invalidate()` and a forceLayout function call in `onSurfaceChanged` and `onSizeChanged` but it doesn't work.
- I point out that the bug only occurs on the "Epson moverio" glasses and i don't understand why.
- Is it a good way to build my own class which inherits from `GLSurfaceView`, and put it into the Activity's layout in order to display 3D or is there another better way to do that kind of feature ?

Here's some snippet of code of my `GLSurfaceView` class implementation

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;
    float angleInDegrees = (360.0f / 10000.0f) * ((int) time);

    if (_trolleyContentInfoList != null && _trolleyCaracteristics != null) {
        _matrixTools.loadIndentity(MatrixType.MODEL_MATRIX);
        drawTrolleyStructure(angleInDegrees);
        drawTrolleyShelves(angleInDegrees);
        //drawTrolleyWheels(angleInDegrees);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspect = (float)width / height;
    float fovy = 60.0f;
    float near = 0.1f;
    float far = 10.0f;

    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _matrixTools.loadIndentity(MatrixType.PROJECTION_MATRIX);
    _matrixTools.perspective(MatrixType.PROJECTION_MATRIX, fovy, aspect, near, far);
    this.forceLayout();
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    this.forceLayout();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    _matrixTools.loadIndentity(MatrixType.VIEW_MATRIX);
    _matrixTools.lookAt(MatrixType.VIEW_MATRIX, 0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    _matrixTools.loadIndentity(MatrixType.MODEL_MATRIX);
    _cubeDrawer = new CubeDrawer();
    _cubeDrawer.initialize();
}
```

And, finally, here's how my custom class inherits from GLSurfaceView

```
public class Trolley3DView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, ITrolleyPreviewView{
}
```

Edit : Okay after a test i've seen that the black square dissapear after typing something into a TextView in the Activity. Must i understand that i should invalidate the Activity in order to force it to refresh when the softkeyboard pops out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i finnaly found the reason of the bug. You have to set the color of the View on which you display openGL content, and the black square will magically disapear.

Comment: I have the same problem. Was the black squares issue actually resolved with that?